# How to get real IFRAME onload height/width with all rendered pics with its natural size

Tags: javascript, iframe, onload

The problem is when IFRAME onload event triggered and I try to get its height with

```
this.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height
```

it returns IFRAME height without rendered pictures width/height. How to get IFRAME real width/height or how to tell IFRAME to set natural height/width to pictures, while they are loading and rendering?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`document.body.scrollHeight` will help you

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

It returns the total height of the document including the overflow content.